# How to get CropImage.Net working?

Tags: asp.net, cropimage.net

I am trying to get the latest version of CropImage.Net working on my site.

I have added ImageResizer.dll and Imazen.Crop.dll to my project, and I am able to run the diagnostics page for ImageResizer, it does not report any errors, only the following warnings:

2 Issues detected:
(Warning):  To potentially see additional errors here, perform an image resize request.
(Warning):  NoCache is only for development usage, and cannot scale to production use.
            Add DiskCache or CloudFront for production use

I have registered the assembly and added a control to the page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Imazen.Crop" Namespace="Imazen.Crop" TagPrefix="ic" %>

<ic:CropImage ID="CropImage1" runat="server" CanvasHeight="300"  ImageID="Image1" CanvasWidth="300" />   <br />
```

Everything look fine, but when I try to access the page I get the following error:

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Imazen.Crop.CropImage.AddFileReferences() +1917
   Imazen.Crop.CropImage.CreateChildControls() +88
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +188
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +59
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +221
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +221
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +221
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +221
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4296
```

Any suggestions or ideas on what I am going wrong?

Thanks,

Eldon

Comment: Here is the newest version of that component. http://imagecropping.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late, but I managed to reproduce your error by not including an asp:Image.

As you can see, the CropImage control references the ID of an Image:

```
<ic:CropImage ID="CropImage1" runat="server" CanvasHeight="300"  ImageID="Image1" CanvasWidth="300" />   <br />
```

Adding an Image with the same ID solves the problem:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/328.jpg" />
```